# Determining whether DAG is semi-connected

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dag

I have been asked to write an algorithm which determine whether a DAG is semi-connected. (Recall that a DAG is semi-connected if for any pair of vertices $x,y$, there is either a path from $x$ to $y$ or a path from $y$ to $x$.)

My idea that that a DAG is semi-connected iff it has a unique topological sort. Therefore, I can use a topological sorting algorithm, checking each time that there is a unique candidate for the next vertex in the topological order.

Does my idea work?

Comment: *Is this idea correct?* If you can show that the algorithm works, then it is correct.

Comment: I do not think your idea is correct. Consider a directed graph with two vertices and no edges. I claim that this graph is a DAG which does not have a unique topological ordering.